# How can I prevent deletion of remote branches in pure GIT

Tags: git, hook, atlassian-sourcetree, git-extensions

The question is in **PURE GIT** not GitHub, GitBucket, GitLab and such.

Is there a way with hooks or anything else, that I can catch the command someone is trying to delete a remote branch ?

Something like the command "push --delete origin branchName"

pre-push or update hooks, doesn't know if a "delete" is executed.

It's very weird that accidentally or without understanding someone can, very simply, delete even a main branches like "master". Its correct that everything could be restored, but why all the hassle ? no way I can mark it as protected or at least some hook that I can check if it is being done ?

We only use GIT with GitExtentions, with simple http, we won't switch to other tools.

Thanks,
Eli.

Comment: As you mentioned remote branches, you do use some remote access. It worth specifying which protocol do you use. The answer of mmlr should work for most of them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration `receive.denyDeletes` can be used for this:

```
$ git config receive.denyDeletes true
```

See [this reference at the very bottom](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

> This denies any deletion of branches or tags – no user can do it. To remove remote branches, you must remove the ref files from the server manually.

Or from the [git config reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-receivedenyDeletes):

> If set to true, git-receive-pack will deny a ref update that deletes the ref. Use this to prevent such a ref deletion via a push.

This would be set on the bare repository, or with `--system` globally for all repositories handled on that system.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed !